# WordPress/WooCommerce Reset Password form not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Wordpress with WooCommerce

I am not sure when this started occurring, but recently a few of my users complained that they are unable to change their passwords. They click on the "Lost Password" link. They receive the email with the link to reset the password.

Upon clicking on the link, they are redirected to "https://…./my-account/lost-password/?show-reset-form=true". However, the Reset Password form does not show up. Instead, they receive the original Lost Password screen prompting them to enter username/email so the Lost Password email can be sent to them.

So the users are in this circular loop. They are unable to change the password.

Any ideeas how to fix this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have any server side caching implemented?

Comment: no i don't have

Comment: Curious that it seems to be answered here: [link]https://www.anterik.com/solved-wordpress-woocommerce-reset-password-form-not-working/

Comment: I tried that. not working :(

Comment: I sent a email to the guys from woocommerce to see what's the problem but they did not answered yet :(

Comment: You mention that "a few users" are having this problem. Can you give us a percentage or is this happening for every user? Do you have any user environment information (Browser, OS etc ...) ?

Comment: I'm sorry.. all of them are having this problem

Comment: It's been discussed in other posts that this problem can be due to **click tracking** plugins such as **SendGrid** . Do you have anything like that installed?

Comment: No. I don't have that plugin installed. I tried to disable all plugins one by one and check if that works and still it doesn't.

Comment: The link in the email usually is some form of `https://example.com/my-account/lost-password/?key=Vpm3WQy1ktwpXQLsYFCx&login=myusername` . Can you post a snippet of the link you are  actually receiving in the email?

Comment: One more question: Are you using any kind of WP hosting environment (WP Engine etc.)?

Comment: This is the code from mail: "<a class="m_-5615294639402646791link" href="https://example.com/my-account/lost-password/?key%5Berrors%5D%5Bempty_captcha%5D%5B0%5D&amp;&amp;id=120" style="color:#557da1;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://example.com/my-account/lost-password/?key%255Berrors%255D%255Bempty_captcha%255D%255B0%255D%26%26id%3D120&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1542215636815000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGDLErb8VCjJ73Gqil8Vt8kfOCTag">  Click here to reset your password </a>"

Comment: And no, I'm not using any kind of wp hosting

Comment: Those are not the correct reset password URL get parameters. There is some sort of error in generating the URL parameters affiliated with  a Captcha/Recaptcha plugin or URL rewrite somewhere in your code. I'll see if I can track it down ....

Comment: It looks like Google is rewriting the link itself. Have you tried picking up the reset password email in an email client other than Google?

Comment: This is most probably being caused by  Captcha/Recaptcha in Woocommerce itself, or another plugin that uses it for all your forms. If you have [This installed][1] , disable it ...  [1]: https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-captcha-recaptcha-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Jamie_D you're a life savior. I'm sorry for my late reply but i was out of country. The problem was caused by Captcha/Recaptcha plugin

Comment: Jamie_D put your answer in "Answer Q": "This is most probably being caused by Captcha/Recaptcha in Woocommerce itself..." for me to be able to vote the answer. And thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Check the reset password url. Replace `&amp;` with `&`.

It helped in my case.